# How to find relative Xpath if element is not having unique identifier

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation

Please someone help me to write relative Xpath for below:

```
html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td
```

As it do not contains any unique identifier firepath is giving an absolute Xpath but i want to use relative Xpath.

Comment: Please Share your HTML code.. We cant create a xpath without knowing your HTML Structure.. copy the HTML code for the element and its parents

Comment: With HTML tables, it's always difficult to do it any different than in your example. But at least things like `div[1]` can usually be spared if there's a `class` attribute or something more unique then simply saying `[1]`. But Shubham is right, you need to post your HTML before anyone can help you.

Comment: @ Shubham Jain plese fin below html code:<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td height="101">
<table width="270" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<td width="80%">
<td width="20%">
<div align="right">
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Verdana" size="2">
<b>$398</b>
</font>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table> I want xpath of element at <b>

Comment: The HTML provided does not contain any attribute like Class/Id/Title etc. Hence, it is difficult to use relative path. This may help //table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]//b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the provided html code doesn't contains any class or id, thus you need to use below mentioned Xpath only:

```
html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/font/b
```

But if you add some class or id in your html like shown below:

```
<html><body><div><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody> <tr> <tr> <tr valign="top"> <td height="101"> <table width="270" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0"> <tbody> <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <td width="80%"> <td width="20%"> <div id="price" align="right"> <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Verdana" size="2"> <b>$398</b> </font> </div> </td> </tr> <tr> <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <tr> <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> </tbody> </table> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table></div></body></html>
```

Then you can use below mentioned Xpath:

```
.//*[@id='price']/font/b
```

Comment: @ Sarabjit Singh Thanks